# How to convert the output of artificial neural network to image?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have used Neural Network Fitting Tool for prediction and simulation flood area. The input data are (DEM, Flow Accumulation, landuse, rainfall, soil, geology, and slop) as maps. The output data is only one map of flood area which happened few years ago. 
I used these function below to make the maps small then convert them to matrix.
((Actually I am not pretty sure if these function are correct or not))

So, can I use the output (result) of this tool as map of expected flood area ? 
If yes. Could you please help me to do that?

```
I1 = imread('DEM.png');
D1 = squeeze(I1);
D1 = reducevolume(D1,[5,5,1]);
G1 = rgb2gray(D1);
H1 = im2double(G1);
input = [H1(:) H2(:) H3(:) H4(:) H5(:) H6(:) H7(:)];
target= [H8(:)];
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you explain what ANN tools are, and maybe give some an example that shows exactly what you did, what you saw, and where you are having trouble? This site works best with concrete questions.

Comment: You can use `imagesc` to convert a matrix or vector to an image. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

Comment: Thank you very much Andy and Macduff. Andy, I rewrote what I have done above.